# Can I use pintool to get what is executed in the source code?

Tags: c++11

Can I use pintool to get what is executed in the source code?

I can now use pintool to get every instruction executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. The binary file contains the machine code generated by your compiler from your source code, but not any kind of source code. There are some tools that can reverse-engineer source code from binaries (or you can do it yourself), but the generated source will have lost all things that are nonessential to the program logic, like variable names etc. Also, since the binaries are usually heavily optimized, even the logic itself might not look too similar to the original source. The closest you can do, which requires you to already have the source, is to compile with debugging flags, which makes the compiler bake in some information which instructions came from which source file/line

Comment: I can locate the address of each instruction executed in the source code.

Comment: I have source files, and binary files are compiled by myself.

Comment: The address of each instruction can be entirely unrelated to the source line, so you need the debugging information. Which platform are you on/what compiler sre you using?

Comment: I am currently using the compiler (GCC) on linux, and the binary file is the debug version.

Comment: I can locate the position of each disassembly instruction in the source code

Comment: I want to determine which lines of source code are executed. Maybe my description is not detailed enough, you can ask in detail.

Comment: So you can figure it out for each individual instruction, but you want to know all source lines executed during a run of your program?

Comment: yes，I   want to know all source lines executed during a run of your program

Comment: int main(int argc, char * argv[])

{
    readTxt();
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    trace = fopen("itrace.out", "w");
    outFile.open("tracefun.out");
    // Initialize pin
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();

    // Register Instruction to be called to instrument instructions
    RTN_AddInstrumentFunction(Routine, 0);
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);

    // Register Fini to be called when the application exits
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);
    
    // Start the program, never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();
    
    return 0;
}

Comment: Can I use it this way?

Comment: RTN_AddInstrumentFunction(Routine, 0);
    INS_AddInstrumentFunction(Instruction, 0);